# knex - building query to ignore columns not present

Tags: knex.js

I have a table that cotains 2 columns: `[one, two]`, just a simple table with 2 columns, and I insert some data to it like this:

```
queryBuilder()
      .withSchema(schema)
      .insert([{one: 1, two: 2}])
      .into(this.table)
      .returning('*');
```

now what I want to do is this:

```
queryBuilder()
      .withSchema(schema)
      .insert([{one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}])
      .into(this.table)
      .someOtherMethodsToAchieveTheFollowing()
      .returning('*');
```

I want knex to just ignore the column `three` and insert the values for `one` and `two`, i.e. effectively ignore values that are not present. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that "not present values" means that the attribute doesn't exist on the variable. (or perhaps the attribute exists with a null value?)

If you pass a variable into the .insert(), then only the attributes included in the variable will be set when the record is inserted into the table.

```
let myStruct = {one: 1, two: 2};
queryBuilder()
      .withSchema(schema)
      .insert(myStruct)
      .into(this.table)
      .returning('*');
// sets fields one and two on the inserted record.

let myStruct2 = {one: 1, two: 2, three: null};
queryBuilder()
      .withSchema(schema)
      .insert(myStruct2)
      .into(this.table)
      .returning('*');
// sets fields one, two, and three on the inserted record.
```

If there are null values (or other values) in your input attributes, and you don't want them to be set in the insert, then you will have to `delete` those attributes off of your input variable.

```
let myStruct3 = {one: 1, two: 2, three: null};
delete myStruct3.three;
// You could build a dynamic loop to test each attribute for null, 
//     then delete any null attributes

queryBuilder()
      .withSchema(schema)
      .insert(myStruct3)
      .into(this.table)
      .returning('*');
// sets fields one and two on the inserted record.
```

Answer (score 0):

Knex actually does not know anything what kind of columns your table `this.table` has so it cannot automatically ignore any fields of the inserted objects.

One has to do it manually or write own extension method to knex, which allows to list allowed columns for the insert. Though it would be pretty much as easy to just write a helper:

```
.insert(pick([obj1, obj2, obj3], ['one', 'two'])
```

or if your `this` has also `columnNames` it would look like:

```
queryBuilder()
      .withSchema(schema)
      .insert(pick([{one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}], this.columnNames))
      .into(this.table)
      .returning('*');
```